# Possible to "retire" a board?

Tags: trello-boards

Is it possible to retire or deactivate a board for projects that are over? I'd like to be able to move projects that are completed, canceled, or on hiatus out of the main organization board and into a hidden or greyed out area without losing any of the people associated with it or having to invite people to multiple organizations.

How are other people dealing with finished project boards?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using **Options -> Close Board...**

You will be able to re-open it on **Boards -> View Closed Boards**